# java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request ([512]) were detected

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, jboss7.x

I have an  with an add button, this button add a row to the datatable like this.

```
public void addDetail(){
  detail.add(new Detail());
  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":theDatatable");
}
```

the problem is when the datatable have too many rows (Ex 200 rows) because the ajax call in the render process have many params, the server throw this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request ([512]) were detected. Any parameters beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.
```

I cant fix this changed the maxParameterCount but the time of the request not change (~2000ms)

My question is: Is posible add an single row via javascript using the widgetVar o something?? Any other solution?

Thanks!!

Edit:

This is part of the xhtml code.

```
    <p:dataTable id="theDatatable" var="_det" rowIndexVar="indexVar"
    style="width:100%;" widgetVar="dataTableDetalleWidget" 
    rendered="#{neLiquidacionController.currentCab.tipoLine==neLiquidacionController.facturar.value}"
    editMode="row" editable="true" 
    value="#{neLiquidacionController.detail}">
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" />
    <p:column headerText="Item" width="40" style="background:#EEEEEE;">
        <h:outputText value="#{indexVar+1}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Descripción">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{_det.productos.descripcion}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:autoComplete id="producto" placeholder="ingrese un valor.."
                    disabled="#{neLiquidacionController.currentCab.estado!='PENDIENTE'}"
                    converter="#{productoConverter}" autocomplete="true"
                    required="true" onfocus="this.select();"
                    onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==27){addDetail();}"
                    completeMethod="#{neLiquidacionController.completeProducto}"
                    var="p" itemLabel="#{p.descripcion}" itemValue="#{p}"
                    scrollHeight="300" forceSelection="true" dropdown="true"
                    value="#{_det.productos}">
                    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" async="true"
                        listener="#{neLiquidacionController.elementChangeProducto}"></p:ajax>
                    <f:facet name="itemtip">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <f:facet name="header">Producto</f:facet>
                            <p:column headerText="Codigo">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{p.codProducto}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Descripcion">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{p.descripcion}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:autoComplete>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<pe:remoteCommand name="addDetail" async="true" partialSubmit="true"
    process="@this" 
    actionListener="#{neLiquidacionController.addDetail()}">
</pe:remoteCommand>
```

With Primefaces 5.0 and PrimeFaces extension 2.0

Firebug request and response.

```
javax.faces.ViewState   3374159165244990485:-1029187269574844262
javax.faces.behavior.even...    keypress
javax.faces.partial.ajax    true
javax.faces.partial.event   keypress
javax.faces.partial.execu...    notaEnvioDet:detalle:98:salida
javax.faces.source  notaEnvioDet:detalle:98:salida
notaEnvioDet:detalle:0:co...    7840048000043
notaEnvioDet:detalle:0:pr...    4

......
notaEnvioDet:detalle:98:pr...   680
notaEnvioDet:detalle:98:pr...   AZUCAR CONFITERO X 1Kg.
notaEnvioDet:detalle:98:sa...   37.0
notaEnvioDet:nroDocumento   824
```

this send all the datatable value... 
And the response here:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="messages"><![CDATA[<span id="messages"></span><script id="messages_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Growl','growlWidget',{id:'messages',sticky:false,life:6000,escape:true,msgs:[]});});</script>]]></update><update id="usuarios:j_idt482"><![CDATA[<div id="usuarios:j_idt482" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[3374159165244990485:-1029187269574844262]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

Comment: The backing bean action method code in the question is irrelevant as the method isn't even reached at all. You'd better show the view (XHTML) code which is supposed to trigger this action method. My guess would be that adding `partialSubmit="true"` to it should do it, if not already tried.

Comment: the ajax call used a pe:remote command of the primefaces extension and this have `partialSubmit="true"`, edit the question adding the xhtml code. Thanks

Comment: OK, how about its `process` attribute? Does it process **only** the relevant data or the entire form?

Comment: Posted part of the firebug log console.. this sends all data in the request.. another way to do this?

Comment: Looks like `partialSubmit="true"` is being ignored. What if you try PrimeFaces own `<p:remoteCommand>` instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you Using Server as a Jboss you can change in standalone.xml is like

```
 <system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="2000"/>
</system-properties>
```